# Disable time slots for provided start date time and end date time in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, slot

I am working on a appointment module where users can book certain timeslots online. I am stuck on 
disabling available time slots within a specific day (or week). I know the length of the needed time slot (eg. 30 minute) and the business hours in which time slots are bookable (eg. 09:00 AM - 06:00 PM). Additionally I have a MySQL table that stores the already existing appointments. The columns relevant to my questions look like this:

```
appo_time_slot_id          appo_time_slot        appo_date_slot     status
       1                   09:00 am - 09:30 am        04/10/2019         0
       2                   09:30 am - 10:00 am        04/10/2019         0 
       3                   09:00 am - 09:30 am        05/10/2019         0
       4                   09:30 am - 10:00 am        05/10/2019         0
```

Now given the information mentioned above, I am unable to find a good solution (in MySQL or PHP) for disabling means (I want to do status=1 in table). There is one more condition: Time slots can only start in given minute. Ie. for the example data above on the table available 30 minute time slots would be:
09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, ..., 11:30, ...,6:00.

Please note that disable column in table i.e. status= 1 that is between startdate,enddate,starttime and endtime. e.g.

```
appo_time_slot_id           appo_time_slot        appo_date_slot     status
       1                   09:00 am - 09:30 am        04/10/2019         1
       2                   09:30 am - 10:00 am        04/10/2019         1 
       3                   09:00 am - 09:30 am        05/10/2019         1
       4                   09:30 am - 10:00 am        05/10/2019         1
```

What would you think is the best way to approach this?

Comment: separating slot start time and slot end time will make your life easy.

Comment: ok, I will make separate start time and slot end time, but question is still remain